# whenever I run a loop it seems to turn my object null after

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have never encountered this before. In Laravel 8, every time I iterate through a collection, it becomes null after.

Example:

```
$loops = Loops::get();
```

inside of loops I have

```
public function loopNotifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LoopNotifications::class, 'loop_id', 'id');
    }

@if($loop->loopNotifications->count()) 
    @foreach($loop->loopNotifications as $loopNotification)
     <li class="px-6 py-2 border-b border-gray-200 w-full">
         <div class="text-lg font-medium">{!!$loopNotification->convertToReadable()!!} 
         </div>
     </li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Before I run this I dd() the loop, and it's all there

After I run the same dd() and it's null. This is happening to every single foreach I run. I started to write for statements just to get past this, but at this point It's frustrating to write all the extra code.

Has anyone had this issue.

Comment: I’m trying to confirm this but I think $loop is a protected word/variable in laravel. You can use it in foreach statements to get info on the loop itself like what iteration it is.

Comment: It is a Laravel variable: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$loop` as a variable in blade.
Laravel uses this variable name to give you insights about the loop itself as you were guessing correctly.
Renaming the variable and try again.

Also on a sidenote you could use the `??` operator instead of putting the whole inside a @if block: (considering you named `$loop` to `$l`)

```
@foreach($l->loopNotifications??[] as $loopNotification)
 <li class="px-6 py-2 border-b border-gray-200 w-full">
     <div class="text-lg font-medium">{!!$loopNotification->convertToReadable()!!} 
     </div>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

This fallsback to an empty array if $loop->loopNotifications is null. It's not required, yours works as well, but IMHO it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks linx that was the issue and that [] example is very helpful, I will use that in all my future programming.